# Does the official RaspPi CameraV2 work on RaspPi B rev2? I'm having trouble

Tags: picamera, pi-b

I have a new official Raspberry Pi Camera V2 and am trying to use it on a Raspberry Pi B revision 2 board running the Sept 24, 2022 version of the Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye.
I have carefully connected the camera and believe I have the cable in the right orientation. However, libcamera-hello and libcamera-jpeg cause a set of errors which I have copied in full below.

Does the V2 camera work with an older Pi board? Any other suggestions?
Thank you, TS

```
libcamera-hello
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:16:40.592354557] [1415]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3866-0c55e522
[0:16:41.047519671] [1422]  WARN RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1258 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[0:16:41.056395420] [1422]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1374 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:16:41.073151945] [1415]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1035 configuring streams: (0) 1640x1232-YUV420
[0:16:41.077448823] [1422]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:761 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 - Selected sensor format: 1640x1232-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1640x1232-pBAA
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  failed to import fd 19
Aborted

libcamera-jpeg
ERROR: *** output file name required ***
caterpi@raspberrypi:~ $ libcamera-jpeg -o image.jpg
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:18:20.988303714] [1430]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3866-0c55e522
[0:18:21.938357094] [1435]  WARN RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1258 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[0:18:21.964226152] [1435]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1374 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:18:21.985468378] [1430]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1035 configuring streams: (0) 1640x1232-YUV420
[0:18:21.994542047] [1435]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:761 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 - Selected sensor format: 1640x1232-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1640x1232-pBAA
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  failed to import fd 19
Aborted
```

Comment: please include full error listing

Comment: I"ve got the full error posted now. Sorry, it dropped the line termination characters for some reason. I can manually put them back in if needed. Thank you, TS

Comment: no need ... just format the listing as code ... put **```** on a **separate line** before the error listing and same after the listing ... done it for you

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't understand the solution, but I found one on an ArduCam page.

1. Enable Glamor graphic acceleration
2. Also, go to GL Driver and select GL (Full KMS).
3. Reboot

https://www.arducam.com/docs/cameras-for-raspberry-pi/pivariety/troubleshooting/#4-failed-to-import-fd-19

My camera still gives a warning:
'''
[0:05:27.946812138] [1082]  WARN RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1258 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
'''

but it does work. If anyone could comment on the warning, that would be great.
Thanks all for looking at my Q.
Best wishes, TS